# how to export all the files path from the debug symbols

Tags: c, gdb

I'm using GCC -g to compile.

In GDB, I use "info sources" to list all the files path (c, cpp, h, etc..)

Now I want to export this result to a file.

One solution was to turn on GDB logging with "set logging on" but it's not exactly what I want:

- I need to type "enter" to export all the results,
- there is "," at the end of the lines
- I want to do this automatically after compilation

**Edit**

One solution could be:

```
#!/bin/sh
gdb -batch -ex "info sources" the_executable > /tmp/list_sources.txt
sed -i -e 's/, /\r\n/g' /tmp/list_sources.txt
grep -e '^\/' /tmp/list_sources.txt > list_sources.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run gdb in batch mode:

```
gdb -batch -ex "info sources" your_program > info_sources.txt
```

Comment: yes, thank you! I found it too few mn ago... After this I'm using sed and grep to format my file correctly